# Angular4 - Unable to access entry components from lazy module

Tags: angular, typescript

In my App Component, I initialized a dynamic modal which renders a dynamic component for the body. I've already added "Selected" entry components I need for the App component.

What I am trying to do is when a Module gets lazy loaded (e.g. Video Page), the module loads its own entry components (e.g. editVideoComponents). I'm trying to show the modal with the dynamic component from the Lazy Loaded module page but I keep on getting "EXCEPTION: No component factory found for MYCOMPONENT. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?"

Any thoughts or idea on how to go about this issue?

Comment: This post: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14324 helped resolve my issue. If anyone has a better solution, please add your solution here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much for linking to that issue!